# Difference between cp and cp -rf

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

Could anybody explain is there any difference between `cp some-file.txt some-folder` and `cp -rf some-file.txt some-folder` on a Mac?

I was told that `cp -rf` forces `cp` to overwrite existing files, but it seems it overwrite them even without `-rf`.

So what is the reason to use `-rf` here then?

Comment: Some cases, not sure about macOS, alias commands to `cp -i` in some cases (e.g. RHEL as root) and the `-f` then overrides the `-i` from the alias... (Not an answer since it is probably not the case on macOS, but might explain some advice on the internet)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard `cp` binary on macOS doesn't have a `-r` option. If you want to copy directories, you need `-R`. Maybe the person telling you this was confusing it with `rm -rf`.

As for `-f`, the man page says

```
If the destination file cannot be opened, remove it and create a new file, 
without prompting for confirmation regardless of its permissions.
```

So, in case the destination file exists but you don't have write access, `cp` usually would fail. `-f` tries to remove the file (which is possible as long as you have write access to the directory) and then replaces it with the copied version.

```bash
$ touch foo bar
$ chmod -w bar
$ cp foo bar
cp: bar: Permission denied
$ cp -f foo bar
$
```